# What does "Illegal assignment from Schema.SObjectField to String" mean?

Tags: apex, trigger

I wrote the following trigger and I'm getting the error :

> Illegal assignment from Schema.SObjectField to String

But I don't know how to fix it. I wrote a similar trigger before and didn't have any issues.

```
trigger AccountDuplicates on Account (before insert, before update) { 
for (Account myaccount : Trigger.new) {
        List <Account> dupes = [SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Name = :(myaccount.Name)]; 
        if (dupes.size() > 0) { 
          myaccount.Duplicate_Account__c = Account.name;
        }
    }
}
```

The purpose of the trigger - when a new account is created that matches the name of an existing account, put the existing account's name into the "Duplicate Account" field.

Comment: Besides the issue you are having, you need to consider [bulkifying you code](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice%3A_Bulkify_Your_Code). You currently have a SOQL statement inside a for loop, which will hit a governor limit if a lot of contacts are inserted/updated

Answer (score 2):

The root problem is the line

```
 myaccount.Duplicate_Account__c = Account.name;
```

This references `Account` (the Schema sobject), not `myAccount`, the loop variable.  Thus you need the following

```
trigger AccountDuplicates on Account (before insert, before update) { 
  for (Account myaccount : Trigger.new) {
    List <Account> dupes = [SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Name = :(myaccount.Name)]; 
    if (dupes.size() > 0) { 
      myaccount.Duplicate_Account__c = myAccount.name;  // myAccount - the trigger loop vbl
    }
  }
}
```

Now, as @barcotter, said, you need to bulkify the trigger as SOQL inside of for loops is a no-no -- when the batch size is >100 as it can easily be in dataloader use cases, the governor limit on SOQL (100) will be exceeded.

I'll leave that as an exercise for you - there are many many resources (Google) on bulkifying triggers

Comment: Thank you for your help! Teaching myself this stuff is not the easiest thing when I have no coding background.

Comment: you will also need to learn to write  a test class - again --many many resources on how to do this, starting with the Apex Developer's Guide

Comment: Sorry @crop1645 I just voided your exercise by posting my answer :-)

Comment: no worries -- i knew someone would do the bulkification

Answer (score 1):

See @crop1645 for the answer as to why your current code isn't working. But there is a larger issue here with [bulkified code](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice%3A_Bulkify_Your_Code). See the example below that will only do one SOQL query no matter how many Accounts are inserted or updated.

```
trigger AccountDuplicates on Account (before insert, before update) { 

    List<String> names = new List<String>();
    for (Account a : Trigger.new) {
            names.add(a.Name);
    }

    Map<String, Account> duplicateMap = new MapMap<String, Account>();
    for (Account dup : [SELECT Name, Id FROM Account WHERE Name in :names]) {
        duplicateMap.put(dup.Name, dup); // Last duplicate found is stored in the map
    }

    for (Account a : Trigger.new) {
        Account dup = duplicateMap.get(a.Name);
        if (dup != null) {
            a.Duplicate_Account__c = dup;
        }     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`List<Account> dupes` should be there instead of just List dupes . And moreover is the field " Duplicate Account"  a text field or a lookup? If its a lookup , name cannot be assigned to it?